Apache Airflow: Dynamic Task Execution Issue - Tasks Not Executing After Split Task
I'm working on migrating a pipeline from the Python schedule library to Apache Airflow. My DAG involves pulling pdf from source, splitting into images, performing OCR on each image, and executing tasks after OCR.
My airflow version is 2.9.0
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests
import os
import json
import logging

load_dotenv()

configuration = json.load(open("config.json"))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def handle_response(response):
    if 200 <= response.status_code < 300:
        try:
            json_data = response.json()
            return json_data
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            return None
    else:
        return None

def _split(**kwargs):
    # Let's assume these are the images from pdf file that i've saved after split
    data = {
        "images": [
            {
                "page_id": 1,
                "image_path": "path/to/image"
            },
            {
                "page_id": 2,
                "image_path": "path/to/image"
            },
            {
                "page_id": 3,
                "image_path": "path/to/image"
            },
            {
                "page_id": 4,
                "image_path": "path/to/image"
            },
            {
                "page_id": 5,
                "image_path": "path/to/image"
            },
            {
                "page_id": 6,
                "image_path": "path/to/image"
            }
        ],
        "status": True,
        "ref_data": [
            {
                "documentName": "type1",
                "documentReferenceId": 1
            },
            {
                "documentName": "type2",
                "documentReferenceId": 2
            },
            {
                "documentName": "type3",
                "documentReferenceId": 2
            }
        ],
        "file_id": 1,
        "configuration": {
            # some configuration
        }
    }

    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='split_data', value=data)

    return {
        'images': data["images"],
        'file_id': 1,
        'configuration': {"okc": "dfafdsaf"},
        "ref_data": data["ref_data"]
    }

def _ocr(image, file_id, configuration, claim_ref_db_data, **kwargs):

    logger.info("into ocr task")

    image_path = image['image_path']
    page_id = image['page_id']
    
    ocr_endpoint = f"{os.getenv('OCR')}/ocr"

    ocr_payload = {'image_path': image_path, "ocr_type":"DocTr/FR/Tesseract", "configuration": configuration}

    logger.info(ocr_payload)
    
    ocr_resp = requests.post(ocr_endpoint, json=ocr_payload)

    ocr_resp_json = handle_response(ocr_resp)

    logger.info(ocr_resp_json)

    ocr_persist_payload = {
        "page_id": page_id,
        "ocr_result": {
            "clean_text": "clean_text", # From ocr service
            "raw_ocr": "raw_ocr" # From ocr service
        },
        "file_id": file_id
    }

    logger.info(ocr_persist_payload)

    ocr_persist_resp = requests.post(f"{os.getenv('DDMS')}/persist_ocr_data", json=ocr_persist_payload)
    
    ocr_persist_json = handle_response(ocr_persist_resp)

    logger.info(ocr_persist_json)

    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='ocr_data', value=ocr_persist_json)
    

def _after_ocr(page_id, **kwargs):
    
    logger.info(f"{page_id} categorization in progress")

    # My logic goes here

    # Data will be pushed to xcom with unique key

# Define default arguments
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': None,
}

# Initialize the DAG
dag = DAG(
    'sample_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='testing pipeline',
    schedule_interval=None,
)

# Define the split task
split_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='split',
    python_callable=_split,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)

# Function to create dynamic OCR and categorization tasks
def create_ocr_and_after_ocr_tasks(**kwargs):
    
    split_data = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='split', key='split_data')
    images = split_data['images']
    file_id = split_data['file_id']
    configuration = split_data['configuration']
    claim_ref_tb_data = split_data['ref_data']

    for image in images:
        
        page_id = image['page_id']
        
        ocr_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f'ocr_{page_id}',
            python_callable=_ocr,
            op_args=[image, file_id, configuration, claim_ref_tb_data],
            provide_context=True,
            dag=dag,
            trigger_rule='all_done'
        )

        logger.info(f"ocr task created {page_id}")

        after_ocr_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f'after_ocr_{page_id}',
            python_callable=_after_ocr,
            op_args=[page_id],
            provide_context=True,
            dag=dag,
            trigger_rule='all_done'
        )

        logger.info(f"after_ocr task created {page_id}")

        create_tasks_op >> ocr_task >> after_ocr_task

        logger.info("dependencies are mentioned")

# Create a PythonOperator to dynamically create OCR and categorization tasks
create_tasks_op = PythonOperator(
    task_id='create_ocr_and_after_ocr_tasks',
    python_callable=create_ocr_and_after_ocr_tasks,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)

# Set task dependencies
split_task >> create_tasks_op

I'm encountering an issue where I'm unable to create and execute dynamic tasks for OCR and tasks after OCR. The split task and the task to create dynamic tasks execute successfully, but the dynamically created tasks for OCR and tasks after OCR are not being executed.
I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm creating and setting dependencies for the dynamic tasks. I'm using XCom to pass data between tasks and provide_context=True to access the TaskInstance (ti).
Any insights into why the dynamic tasks are not executing or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.
